# In the method of the parent class take fields values from all of the derived classes in c#

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

For example I have this classes:

```
public class Car{
 public string color;
 public double price;
}

public class YellowCar{...}

public class RedCar{...}
```

and in the class Car I want to write a method that would display information about "inherited" fields from his derived classes so it would look like this:

```
public class Car{
 public string color;
 public double price;

 public void DisplayMethod(){
  //display field **color** and field **price** from the instance of the YellowCar class
  //...then display the same fields from the instance of the RedCar class   
 }
}
```

I don't wanna use a method that would take a derived class instance as a parameter and display its fields so I need to invoke this method a couple of times for every instance.
Is there an option in program architechture to write something close to the method i've mentioned before? And if it is what does it is and how does it works?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the instance of the YellowCar class" and "the instance of the RedCar class" - what instances? Could you provide a more full concrete example?

Comment: creating `YellowCar/RedCar` classes does make sens if the only difference is the property in base class

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is exactly one case, where inheritance helps you out. (Although if the differences stay this "limited" it is probably an overkill to create separate classes for that)

In your first class "Car" you can simply print your variables like so:

```
public class Car{
 public string color;
 public double price;

 public void DisplayMethod(){
  Console.WriteLine($"Color: {color}, price: {price.ToString("C")}");  
 }
}
```

The inheriting classes would then be responsible for setting these values. For example:

```
public class YellowCar : Car
{
   public void YellowCar(double _price){
    color = "yellow";
    price = _price;
   }
}
```

The inheriting classes (`YellowCar` and `RedCar`) have access to the fields of the class they inherit (`Car`) and thus they can simply set them. So if you write a printing-Method like `DisplayMethod()` it can print these values.

The usage could then be like this:

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
   YellowCar expensiveYellowCar = new YellowCar(100000);
   expensiveYellowCar.DisplayMethod();


   YellowCar cheapYellowCar = new YellowCar(100);
   cheapYellowCar .DisplayMethod();
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Which should give the output:

"Color: yellow, price: 100'000,00 €"

"Color: yellow, price: 100,00 €"

(Although the price output depends on your specific Windows-Localization because of the `ToString("C")` method, which uses your local style of formatting currencies.

Comment: So I need to call Display() method for every object and there is no way to call a similar method specified in the parent class only once for all "derived objects". OK, thanks

Comment: Well, there are always ways to achieve things - but in your case you could maybe create a class called `CarGarage` or `CarCollection` which has a `List<Car>` field, and a `AddCar(Car carToAdd)` method. This `CarCollection` class could then have a method `DisplayAllCars()` which iterates through the List and calls `DisplayMethod()` (which by the way is not an optimal name) on all of them.